# t.resolve is not a function in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework

My use case:

Call JavaScript function from JS file (included in project) in Ionic 4 on particular page.

I'm having following issue.

```html
ERROR TypeError: t.resolve is not a function
at Object.setNativePromise (polyfills.js:3)
at L.configurable.L.set (polyfills.js:3)
at n.exports (ocw.js:4850)
at a (ocw.js:4850)
at Object.209.100 (ocw.js:4851)
at s (ocw.js:4850)
at ocw.js:4850
at Object.327.131 (ocw.js:4852)
at s (ocw.js:4850)
at ocw.js:4850
```

Steps followed:

1. Included JS file under src->assets
2. added reference in index.html after cordova.js file

```html
<!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <!-- <script src="assets/ocw.js"></script> -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  
  <script src="assets/ocw.js"></script>
```

3. In desired file, declared variable as function name
4. called javascript function under, ionViewDidLoad

Ionic setup:

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 6.4.0, ios 4.5.5
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.0.2, (and 9 other plugins)

System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2
ios-sim : 6.0.0
NodeJS : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 6.4.1
OS : macOS
Xcode : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

Answer (score -1):

You need to `export` the function in your javascript file and then `import` it in your `pagename.page.ts` to be able to use it.

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried this as well. It is working fine on my Login page but if I try to put it on any other page, I am getting same error

Comment: @GirishFuluskar You'll need to import it for every page you want to use it on.